# Can I be sure about the legality of the applications in Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, youtube, legal

Is it legal to download Youtube videos via KTube?

Comment: please ask a lawyer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not illegal to download YouTube videos for personal use. It is also not illegal that packages like youtube-dl and the ktube-media-downloader snap package are included in the default Ubuntu repositories.

youtube-dl is free software that is dedicated to the public domain under the terms of the [Unlicense](https://unlicense.org/).

Ktube is proprietary software. The application allows users to download two links daily for free. To get full access to the application you have to upgrade the application to pro.

Comment: “It is not illegal to download YouTube videos for personal use.” This sentence does not seem to be true, at least not for every situation, see https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/is-it-legal-to-download-youtube-videos/ and https://www.express.co.uk/life-style/science-technology/1002646/Youtube-download-how-to-download-youtube-videos-music-converter-illegal-MP3.

Comment: Indeed, I think one has to distinguish between whether a software is "legal" and whether using it is "legal".  I have a feeling that the first question is suitable for askubuntu, but the second one should be directed to people who have a better understanding of the laws of that country.  I think it's out of scope of askubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

How you use that tool; where in the world you are; what you choose to download from youtube, will determine whether what you do is legal or illegal as will whether the video in question is protected under any laws.